Sublime Text: Python module missing after update
I recently installed pandas through Anaconda and have been using it fine. I just updated my Sublime Text through the automatic update, and now Sublime Text cannot find my pandas.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Sublime Text and reverting to a freshly installed state by following: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/revert.html, but it only made the file path weirder and more wrong when I just try to import pandas:
import pandas

I get the result:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
[Finished in 104ms with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', 'file_path']]
[dir: directory_path]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin]

I am on Mac OS Sonoma 14.6.1 with Sublime Text Build 4189.
If I run
import sys
print(sys.executable)
print(sys.version)

I get
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
3.9.6 (default, Feb  3 2024, 15:58:28) 

The path is not the same as it was before the update, before it was in
/usr/bin/python 3

Also there is an issue that if I run from Terminal
python -V

I get
Python 3.12.7

which does not match the version that Sublime Text is using. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Sublime Text
My python3.sublime-build file is:
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],     
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",     
    "selector": "source.python"
}

I have also tried:
{
  "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.python"
}

but this does not change anything.
